# Getting joint distribution from the distributions of linear combinations

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real-valued random variables. Let $Z_{a,b}=aX+bY$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, the distribution of $Z_{a,b}$ is known. Then the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is uniquely determined. This is because from the distributions of $Z_{a,b}$, we get the characteristic function of $(X,Y)$, which delivers the unique joint distribution.

My question is that, if we only know the distributions of $Z_{a,b}$ for some pairs of $(a,b)$, when can we recover a unique joint distribution of $(X,Y)$? Any reference for this type of question?

In general, we can't. For example if we only know the distributions of $Z_{1,0}=X$ and $Z_{0,1}=Y$, we can construct many different joint distributions.

But what would happen if we know the distributions of many $Z_{a,b}$? in particular, infinitely many? For example, suppose we know the distributions of $Z_{a,b}$ for all $a\geq 0$ and $b\geq 0$, can we recover the joint distribution? If not, what is the counter example?

Comment: Your critique was, of course, completely valid. I'll correct my approach. I think my idea wasn't completely off.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Yes, you pointed out a good direction to tackle this question. I shall try to construct two different positive definite functions that agree on some subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ closed under multiplication. It just not easy to construct such functions. Positive definite functions are complicated objects......

Comment: I found that if we observe the distribution of $aX+bY$ for all $a,b\geq 0$, we can compute $E[X^nY^m]$ for all non-negative integers $n,m$. Then my question becomes the classic moment problem. In some situations, knowing all moments is sufficient for recovering a unique joint distribution. This would be the case if the support of $(X,Y)$ is compact.